# C++ returning shared_ptr value from function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, shared-ptr

First of all, I'm trying to create my own Vector class (based on STL Vector), just to practice a bit of C++. Unfortunately, I ran into some problems when I started to use shared_ptr.

```
template <class T>
class MyVector{
    std::shared_ptr<T> p_array;
    int p_size; 
    int p_capacity; 
public:
    MyVector();
    void pushBack(T);
    T getBegin();      
};
```

Constructor

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector() : p_capacity(2), p_size(0) {
    std::shared_ptr<T> p_array(new T[p_capacity], std::default_delete<T[]>() );     
}
```

pushBack method

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::pushBack(T m_element) {
    p_array.get()[p_size] = m_element;
    p_size++;
}
```

getBegin method

```
template <class T> 
T MyVector<T>::getBegin() {
    return p_array.get()[0];
}
```

Then in main

```
int main(){
    MyVector<int> test;
    test.pushBack(4);
    cout << "Begin of vector: " << test.getBegin();
}
```

And what I got after compiling it with g++ is Segmentation fault (core dumped)
What I want to get is just value of first element added to vector. If its done on raw pointers everything works fine.

Comment: Your constructor has a *local* variable with the same name as the member - it doesn't initialize the member. Remove the `std::shared_ptr<T>` before `p_array` in the constructor

Comment: When you have a segmentation fault, compile your program with the `-g3` compiler flag, and run it using either `valgrind` or `gdb`, this way you can have additional information. This most likely comes from you trying to use/dereference an un-initialized pointer

Comment: fyi: `std::shared_ptr` implies shared ownership.  Unless you plan to share the ownership of `p_array` in some way, your design is probably more suited to using `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: First of all, If I remove std::shared<ptr>T before p_array in constructor Ill get  error:                                                                                                 no match for call to ‘(std::shared_ptr<int>) (int*, std::default_delete<int []>)’.

Comment: Valgrind shown this:                                                                          ==13121== Invalid write of size 4
==13121==    at 0x402FE3: MyVector<int>::pushBack(int) (my_vector.cpp:15)
==13121==    by 0x402D46: main (main.cpp:9)
==13121==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: Made std::shared_ptr<T[ ]> p_array in header and removed that from source file. Still got error I posted before. Adding [ ] caused even more errors: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
  p_array.get()[p_size] = m_element;

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the problem you are having.

The first one is that your constructor creates a *local* variable with the same name as the member, which means it doesn't assign to the member. Changing the constructor to:

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector() : p_capacity(2), p_size(0) {
    p_array(new T[p_capacity], std::default_delete<T[]>() );     
}
```

Will however lead to a compilation error, as the member variable has already been constructed before the body of the class constructor is called (using the default constructor in this case) and you cannot construct it again. So the simplest way to make this code compile and "work" is to use an assignment:

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector() : p_capacity(2), p_size(0) {
    p_array = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T[p_capacity], std::default_delete<T[]>() );     
}
```

Note however that this is a bit misleading, as `shared_ptr<T>` would usually indicate that it holds a pointer to a *single* element. As of C++17 the rules for smart pointers for arrays have been adjusted to allow you to use `shared_ptr<T[]>` as well.

BUT: As pointed out by Richard Critten, a `unique_ptr` may be more appropriate in this case, as your `MyVector` class is the sole owner of the array.

In fact, `std::unique_ptr` supports `T[]` as template parameter and can lead to simplifications in your code:

First of you can change your class declaration to:

```
class MyVector{
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> p_array; //clearer that it is holding an array
    // rest remains unchanged
```

and your constructor can (using C++14 `std::make_unique`) become:

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector() : p_capacity(2), p_size(0) {
    p_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(p_capacity);     
}
```

Further `std::unique_ptr` also has an overload for the `operator[]`, meaning you can also remove the `.get()` (in `pushBack` and `getBegin`), e.g.:

```
template <class T> 
T MyVector<T>::getBegin() {
    // should check first that p_size is bigger 0!
    return p_array[0];
}
```

Comment: @curiousguy since you know the real reason compilation fails it would have been nice if you had mentioned it, so that I could fix the answer

Comment: It's difficult to explain because **your understanding of explicit is completely wrong.** 1) That ctor is not marked explicit. 2) Only one-arg ctors have to be marked explicit. **All multiple arg ctors are inherently explicit.** An explicit ctor is just one that does not define an implicit conversion. A conversion is inherently from type A to type B. There are no tuples in core C++. You couldn't have a conversion (implicit or explicit) between an argument list and a type.

Comment: @curiousguy So *why* does `p_array(new T[p_capacity], std::default_delete<T[]>() );` fail to compile? I still need that information to be able to fix the answer

Comment: @curiousguy thanks, that was all I wanted to know. Though you could just have lead with that instead of a lecture about explicit constructors